# AWS .Net SDK Create an Amazon EC2 instance with a specific EBS Volume Size

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, ec2-ami

I am developing a .net web application that creates and manages ec2 instances programatically. As of now, when I create new instances, the size of the disk volume is fixed: defined by the image (AMI) I believe.

I would like to Predefine the size of the disk volume when creating a new instance so that I don't need to run a resize operation afterwards. Is that possible? Which would be the best approach?

I have a few ideas:

1. Define the volume size on the RunInstancesRequest object. But I think there is no such option.
2. Create a copy of the AMI image with a different disk size and use that one to request a new EC2 instance. Can this be done?
3. Any other/better ways?

In case that helps, I attach the code I currently use to request new instances:

```
var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
    {
        ImageId = amiID,
        InstanceType = type,
        MinCount = 1,
        MaxCount = 1,
        SecurityGroupIds = groups
    };
    var launchResponse = ec2Client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
    var instances = launchResponse.Reservation.Instances;
    var myInstance = instances.First();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the (integer GiB) value of the **VolumeSize** of the **EbsBlockDevice** in the *launchRequest*.**BlockDeviceMappings** before launch.

Remember that if you specify a snapshot, the volume size must be equal to or larger than the snapshot size. Also, if you're creating the volume from a snapshot and don't specify a volume size, the default is the snapshot size.

**TIP**: Always check the Boolean value of **DeleteOnTermination** as well and do not assume it has a default value of *True* for root volumes as in AWS console.

[You can find out more on EbsBlockDevice properties here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2EbsBlockDevice.html)

Comment: Actually it is not exactly what I intended. This creates a second EBS volume: there is one based on the ImageId and another empty one defined on the `launchRequest.BlockDeviceMappings`. I preferred to have a single larger volume.

Comment: I think you can accomplish what you want by setting the SnapshotId parameter to the ID of the AMI root volume's snapshot

Comment: I don't really understand that. An AMI doesn't have a SnapshotId, does it?

Comment: It's the snapshot ID of the AMI's root volume (the one you're trying to change its size)

Comment: Do you know where to find it in the AMIs section of the AWS Dashboard?

Comment: You can find it under Block Devices in the AMI Details tab. You should see something similar to /dev/sda1=snap-d4571cc7:30:true:gp2 (the SnapshotId here is: snap-d4571cc7)

Comment: In the block device mappings, use deviceName attribute to point to the root volume. It is usually `/dev/sda1`, but you will have to confirm in the AMI. Once you have specified deviceName, you can specify number of properties, like disk size, disk type, iops etc.